# Help understanding basic definition involving Primitive Roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need some help understanding the language of the following theorem and help for how to prove it. Please note that my understanding of Number Theorem is only at the most basic and elementary level.

> For a prime $p$ and a natural number $d$, at most $\phi(d)$ incongruent integers modulo $p$ have order $d$ modulo $p$

So the *order* of a modular congruence is the smallest value $k$ which satisfies $a^k\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. That is, the order of modulo $n$ is the value $k$. The word "incongruence" for Number Theory means that two numbers have a different remainder when divided by the same number. So "incongruent integers modulo $p$" represents $a\neq b\pmod{p}$.

Where I'm confuse is the phrase "have order $d$ modulo $p$". I think it may be telling me that the incongruent integers $a$ and $b$ have the same order  $d$ when in the form $a^d\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ and $b^d\equiv 1\pmod{n}$. Is this correct?

Following that, what exactly do I need to prove in this theorem? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Yes, I think you understand the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nomenclature is a bit off.

“Order” does not refer to a congruence, it refers to an element. Here, “the (multiplicative) order of $a$ modulo $n$” is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $a^k\equiv 1\pmod{n}$. The “order modulo $n$” is attached to $a$, not to a congruence. (You *could* say it attaches to a *congruence class*, but you aren’t using that language in your post.)

Two integers $a$ and $b$ a “congruent modulo $n$” if and only if $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$. They are “incongruent modulo $n$” if and only if this does not occur, that is, $a\not\equiv b\pmod{n}$. Depending on how you defined “congruent modulo $n$”, that could mean to you “different remainders when divided by $n$”, or it could mean “$n$ does not divide the difference $a-b$”.

The statement says: there are at most $\phi(d)$ integers $a_1,\ldots,a_{\phi(d)}$, such that:

1. $a_i\equiv a_j\pmod{p}$ if and only if $i=j$; (equivalently, if $i\neq j$ then $a_i\not\equiv a_j\pmod{p})$ **and**
2. The order of $a_i$ modulo $p$ is $d$ for $i=1,\ldots,\phi(d)$.

You cannot have a list of more than $\phi(d)$ integers that satisfy both 1 and 2 above.

What you need to show is that if you already have a list with $\phi(d)$ integers satisfying 1 and 2 above, and $b$ is any integer such that the order of $b$ modulo $p$ is $d$, then $b$ must be congruent to (at least, but because of item 1, exactly) one of $a_1,\ldots,a_{\phi(d)}$. (Or a statement equivalent to this assertion.).

Comment: I'm confused by your hint of how to prove the theorem. If $\phi(d)$ is a set of incongruent integers, why are we bothering to show that there is an integer $b$ congruent to one of the integers in $\phi(d)$?

Comment: @BobbyB I did not say “$\phi(d)$ is a set” of any kind. $\phi(d)$ is a number. What the hint says is that to show there are *at most* $\phi(d)$ incongruent integers, one way is to show that if you already have $\phi(d)$ incongruent integers, then you cannot find any other integer satisfying both (1) and (2). In particular, any integer satisfying (1) must *not* satisfy (2). (cont)

Comment: @BobbyB: Analogy: let’s say you want to prove that you have at most $7$ cats as pets. One way would be to show that if cat(1) through cat(7) are your pets, all different from each other, then every other animal is either not a cat or not your pet. But to prove that, you can show that any other *cat* is not your pet.

Comment: Okay, I think I fixed my confused. $\phi(d)$ represents the number of elements in the set of incongruent integers $a_1,\ldots,a_{\phi(d)}$. Is this correct?

Comment: I think I understand the logic of how the proof could work. We must show that only the integers $a_1,\ldots,a_{\phi(d)}$ satisfy the points (1) and (2) by showing that there exists no other integer which can satisfy said points. I honestly have no idea how to even begin proving this. How do I discover the mathematical rigor to create this abstract proof?

Comment: @BobbyB: Question 1, yes. Question 2: In my personal opinion, you are thinking about the process backwards. You don’t first find “mathematical rigor” and then create a proof. Rather, you get an idea of how the proof should go, and then you try to make that idea rigorous. As to how to go about proving this... that will depend entirely on what you already know or do not know about how integers modulo $p$ behave under multiplication, information that (i) you have not provided; and (ii) might be too long to list anyway. The suggested path is not the only one, it’s just *a* path.

Comment: I'm familiar with the very basics of Fermat's Little Theorem and Lagrange's Theorem along with the basic properties of modular arithmetic. But absolutely no ideas come to mind for how to form the proof. Thanks for helping me understand the theorem but the proof is beyond my intelligence.